# How manage Calling 2 Classes Objects in 3rd Class

Tags: android, class, object

I got Error from other class object.
I want to do when one class Custom call DownloadedTrack make no Disturbance and same for other
So how i manage 2 Class Objects in 3rd Class's Method.

public class mediademo extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,
        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

```
    Custom custObj = new Custom();
DownloadedTrack dTrack= new DownloadedTrack();
.
.
.
.
public void playSong(int songIndex) {
        System.out.println("Inside playSong with songIndex " + songIndex);
        custObj.setFlag(songIndex);
        dTrack.setFlag(songIndex);
        Log.e("playsong", songIndex + "");
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: What error you got exactly?

Comment: please give more detail about error or exception.

Comment: please post the relevant portion of the `adb logcat` output, including the "caused by" clause, if any